# Community Wiki or Answer to my own Question (gcc-doc non free)

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, self-answer

I want to share some info regarding Debian and GCC. (I needed to add non-free repos to my sources.list file in order to be able to fetch gcc-doc package -***manpages for gcc***-. I search for an explanation and I found it, *thanks Google!*. And I want to share it here, well, not exactly here, but in the main site.

Can I do that? and if I can, How is the best way to do it? 
Do I create a wiki question/post?
Do I use the '*Answer your own question*' checkbox and effectively answer my own question?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both, although there's no need to make it a wiki. Post a question along the lines of "Why can't I fetch the gcc-doc package on Debian?" with a description of what goes wrong when you try without the non-free repos, and then post your own answer with the solution. Just try to keep them distinct; the question should really be a question somebody who doesn't already know the answer would ask, it shouldn't have part of the answer in it

Comment: ok, done. I think I did it right, if not, please send me a clue. oh and by the way, YES, I totally steak your idea of a title, and nope, it isn't just a exact retype, it's a vile, plagiarist, copy-paste. hehe!